# How to Check Delphi TADOConnection.State

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe2

I have a method which performs some operations on a `TADOConnection` object, which sometimes seems to occur when the connection is in a state which would not permit this operation. When this happens, an exception is thrown and processing fails. I want to enclose the method in an `if` statement which simply checks the state of the `TADOConnection` to ensure it is closed before proceeding.

Therefore, I have the following:

```
procedure MyClass.OperateOnADOConnection;
begin
  if ADOConnection.State = stClosed then
  begin
    //do my operations
  end;
end;
```

I get a compile time error for this, because `State` and `stClosed` are apparently not the same object type. I also tried `if ADOConnection.State = TObjectStates.stClosed then` but then I got a different error.

Delphi documentation is pretty limited and doesn't really explain how things are used, as far as I can see. I do not have access to a Delphi IDE as I am not usually a Delphi programmer and licenses are limited - so I am using Visual Studio Code. No online tutorials that I have found make mention of the `.State` property, either.

How am I supposed to use this property?

Comment: How about `TObjectState.stClosed in ADOConnection.State`? Property `ADOConnection.State` is of type `TObjectStates` which is defined as set: `TObjectStates = set of TObjectState`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `State` property is defined as a [*Set*](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) of [`TObjectState`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TObjectState) values:

> A set is a collection of values of the same ordinal type. The values have no inherent order, nor is it meaningful for a value to be included twice in a set.

The `State` can hold multiple `TObjectState` values at one time.  You are trying to compare the entire `Set` to a specific value, which is why you are getting errors. You should instead be checking if the desired value is *contained within* the `Set`.  You can use the `in` operator for that purpose, eg:

```
//if ADOConnection.State = stClosed then
if stClosed in ADOConnection.State then
```